# Persist Values for DropDownList Editor Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, drop-down-menu, selectlist, mvc-editor-templates

I have this on my view and this works well, persisting the country selected:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.CountryList ,"Select Country") %>
```

However when I create an editor template for this, the country selected is not persisted

So, I change my current view to this:

```
 <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryId,new { countries = Model.CountryList}) %>
```

Then I create my editor template like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Int64?>" %>
<%= Html.DropDownList(
        String.Empty /* */, 
        (SelectList)ViewData["countries"], 
        Model
    )
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

Code in parent view:

```
 <% Html.RenderPartial("YourPartialView", Model) %>
```

Code in editor view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ModelFromParent>" %>
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    String.Empty /* */, 
    new SelectList(Model.Countries,"Id", "Title"), 
    "Select Country"
)
```

%>

I didn't compile this. But you get the general idea.

Comment: actually the above code is working i just forget to remove the old code on the first line. This is another great idea